# Why does close() not do anything?

Tags: google-apps-script

Does the app.close() not do anything? it does not appear to work....
// Script-as-app template.
Sample code

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var button = app.createButton('Click Me');
  var closeButton = app.createButton('Close It');
  app.add(closeButton);
  app.add(button);

  var label = app.createLabel('The button was clicked.')
                 .setId('statusLabel')
                 .setVisible(false);

  var label2 = app.createLabel('The Close button was clicked.')
                 .setId('statusLabel2')
                 .setVisible(false);
  app.add(label);
  app.add(label2);
  var closeHandler = app.createServerHandler('close');
  closeHandler.addCallbackElement(label);
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('myClickHandler');
  handler.addCallbackElement(label);
  closeButton.addClickHandler(closeHandler);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);

  return app;
}

function myClickHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var label = app.getElementById('statusLabel');
  label.setVisible(true);

  app.close();
  return app;
}
function close(e)
{
  Logger.log("Here");
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var label2 = app.getElementById('statusLabel2');
  label2.setVisible(true);
  return app.close();
}
```

Link to sample code
https://script.google.com/a/macros/scotts.com/s/AKfycbz-avIT3bZNJ68_EpRZYXmh66XLJzYI--F0n7DGNn8jL_wlG1k/exec

Comment: a simple search on STO search engine for [google-apps-script] close() would have given you all the answers you needed with a lot of examples...

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_uiinstance#close):

> "This will only work if the app is being shown as a dialog, such as in
>   a Google Spreadsheet. It will have no effect when called on an app
>   that is published as a standalone service."

That's a fundamental limit of browsers, by the way - a page can't close itself.

Comment: Well technically it is possible for a browser page to close itself in general if certain conditioans are given, but in terms of Google Apps Script also note that `window.close()` won't work due to Caja (http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) being used.

Comment: It's only generally possible to close windows created via JavaScript, which will usually not be the case. Regardless, app.close() does not even attempt to do that; what it does do is well documented.